# JavaScript regular expression for matching start and end of string and priting the whole string within matched value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the string in one variable

String

```
{"index":"logstash-cdr","search_type":"count","ignore_unavailable":true}
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1451586600000,"lte":1483208999000,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"size":0,"aggs":{"2":{"terms":{"field":"PhoneNumber","size":100000,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}}
{"index":"logstash-cdr","ignore_unavailable":true}
{"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"require_field_match":false,"fragment_size":2147483647},"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1451586600000,"lte":1483208999000,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"size":50,"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"fields":["*","_source"],"script_fields":{},"fielddata_fields":["@timestamp"]}
{"index":"logstash-fraud","search_type":"count","ignore_unavailable":true}
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1451586600000,"lte":1483208999000,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"size":0,"aggs":{"2":{"terms":{"field":"PhoneNumber","size":100000,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}}
{"index":"logstash-fraud","ignore_unavailable":true}
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1451586600000,"lte":1483208999000,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"require_field_match":false,"fragment_size":2147483647},"size":50,"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"fields":["*","_source"],"script_fields":{},"fielddata_fields":["@timestamp"]}
```

but I want just

```
{"index":"logstash-fraud","search_type":"count","ignore_unavailable":true}
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}},{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1451586600000,"lte":1483208999000,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"size":0,"aggs":{"2":{"terms":{"field":"PhoneNumber","size":100000,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}}
```

this line to be printed How can I achieve the same through JavaScript?

Comment: _java-script_ ? It should be JavaScript. and Is it really string.... seems to me javascript objects.

Comment: I am storing this in variable

Comment: Then how do you know it is string/Object or other type.

Comment: Are you reading this from a file ? It don't looks correct javascript. The comma is missing between objects

Comment: its an object which I am storing in variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are storing the string in a variable `a` . You can do the use `substring()` method as follows

```
var start =  a.indexOf('{"index":"logstash-fraud"');
c = a.substring(start,a.indexOf('{"index',start+1));
```